# Редакция вопросительного предложения

Tags: пунктуация

И все же, как создается изобретение, есть какие-то правила, приемы и т. п.?

Это предложение содержит два вопроса. Можно ли его отредактировать так:

И все же, как создается изобретение — есть какие-то правила, приемы и т. п.?

Или лучше так?

И все же — как создается изобретение? Есть какие-то правила, приемы и т. п.?

И кроме того, запятая после "все же", по-моему, не нужна.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если в вашем предложении было два самостоятельных вопроса, тогда последний вариант был бы приемлем.  В вашем же предложении один вопрос с уточнением.

Поэтому можно оформить так:

> И все же, как создается изобретение — есть какие-то правила, приемы и т. п.?
>
> И все же, как создается изобретение, есть какие-то правила, приемы и т. п.

Слова  ***а все же, а все-таки***, стоящие в начале предложения, могут отделяться запятой при интонационно-логическом подчеркивании.

> Ср.: «А всё-таки, мсье Алферов не прав», – неожиданно вставила Клара и проворно поправила прическу. В. Набоков, Машенька.

Answer (score 0):

Вариант:

*И все же, как создается изобретение? Существуют **ли** какие-**либо** правила, приемы и т. п.?*

Comment: Хотя вариант "разбить на два" мне тоже кажется приемлемым, особенно с добавлением частицы "ли". Мне кажется, тут существует множество вариантов. И даже с двоеточием.

Comment: _Alenka: "Мне кажется, тут существует множество вариантов"._ === Конечно.

Answer (score 0):

**Если соблюдать интонацию,** то возможны два варианта:

1) Более спокойный и краткий вариант: И все же, как создается изобретение, есть какие-то правила, приемы и т. п.?

2) Более эмоциональный и подробный вариант: И все же — как создается изобретение? Есть какие-то правила, приемы и т. п.?

В предложении "И все же, как создается изобретение — есть какие-то правила, приемы и т. п.?" сложно изобразить присоединительное тире, которое должно сопровождаться **понижением голоса**.

"И всё же" здесь обособляется, так как в этой структуре **его необходимо интонационно обозначить.**

В любом случае понижение голоса внутри вопросительного предложения нежелательно.

Comment: Вера, как вы думаете, это сложное предложение?

Comment: Сложное, так как две предикативные основы.